How to use net_eth_carrier_on() in Zephyr?
I am running a project using Zephyr 2.4, my goal is to check if the Ethernet cable is physically connected or not.
I saw they have these functions available :
net_eth_carrier_on and net_eth_carrier_off
https://docs.nordicsemi.com/bundle/ncs-latest/page/zephyr/connectivity/networking/api/ethernet.html
However, it seems like I should't be calling these functions directly, because they are used to inform the driver if the cable is connected or not

Inform ethernet L2 driver that ethernet carrier is detected.
This happens when cable is connected.
Parameters:
iface – Network interface

This is my code:

static struct net_if *iface;
static struct net_mgmt_event_callback mgmt_cb;

static void ethernet_event_handler(struct net_mgmt_event_callback *cb,
                                   uint32_t mgmt_event,
                                   struct net_if *iface)
{

  bool is_carrier_on = net_if_flag_is_set(iface, NET_IF_UP);

  if (is_carrier_on) {
    printk("Ethernet carrier is ON\n");
  } else {
    printk("Ethernet carrier is OFF\n");
  }
  if (mgmt_event == NET_EVENT_IF_UP) {
      if (net_if_is_up(iface)) {  
          LOG_INF("Ethernet cable connected.");
      } else {
          LOG_INF("Ethernet interface is up, but the cable is disconnected.");
      }
  } else if (mgmt_event == NET_EVENT_IF_DOWN) {
      LOG_INF("Ethernet cable disconnected.");
  } else {
      LOG_INF("Ethernet cable event: %d", mgmt_event);
  }
}

bool start_ethernet_carrier_detection(void)
{
  struct in_addr ip_addr1, ip_addr2;
   struct net_if_addr *if_addr;
   
  LOG_INF("Starting Ethernet Carrier Detection");

  iface = net_if_get_default();
  if (iface == NULL) {
      LOG_ERR("No default network interface found!");
      return false;
  }else{
    LOG_INF("Default network interface found!");
  }

  net_mgmt_init_event_callback(&mgmt_cb, ethernet_event_handler,
                                NET_EVENT_IF_UP | NET_EVENT_IF_DOWN);
  net_mgmt_add_event_callback(&mgmt_cb);

  LOG_INF("Ethernet Carrier Detection successfully started.");
  return true;
}

This is part of my debug log:

[00:00:07.568,572] [0m<inf> Main: Starting Ethernet Carrier Detection
[0m
[00:00:07.568,603] [0m<inf> Main: Default network interface found![0m
[00:00:07.568,695] [0m<inf> Main: Ethernet Carrier Detection successfully started.
[0m
[00:00:07.568,725] [0m<inf> Main: Ethernet Carrier Detection is running.
[0m
...
[00:00:22.197,052] [0m<inf> Modem: Succeeded to queue event: Socket check buffer
[0m
Ethernet carrier is ON
[00:00:22.197,113] [0m<inf> Main: Ethernet cable connected.[0m

This happens with the cable disconnected, that is why it seems like my program just detects if the interface is up.
How can I actually check if the cable is connected or not? How can I have access to the information provided by net_eth_carrier_on/net_eth_carrier_off?
Ps: I already checked the IP address of the interface to make sure I was checking the right one
I expected my code to return if the Ethernet cable is connected or not

What about pinging the remote host you want to talk to?

I could indicate the connection is down, but would not tell me if the cable is connected or disconnected.
